# Want to change h1 to the text user inputs inside an input box after they click the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a complete newbie, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. I want "Hello world" to change to either "I love Dogs" if the user inputs Dogs into the input box, or change "Hello World" to "Why not Dogs?!" if they don't put Dogs into the input box.

When the user puts text and then clicks submit I run the if statement to see if it is Dogs or not. Then I want to replace h1 with a different h1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<input id="inputBox"><id/>
<button onclick="changeInputBoxText()">Submit</button>
<script>
    function changeInputBoxText()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("inputBox")==="Dogs")
        {
            $("h1").replaceWith("<h1>I love Dogs</h1>");
        }
        else
        {
            $("h1").replaceWith("<h1>Why not dogs?!</h1>");
        };
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something [___like this___](http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5Cy/).. Even you can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Comment: I think I figured out why your guy's solutions weren't working. I was using the codecademy codbit editor, but a ton of other people were having trouble getting it to recognize jquery. I will try to use the fiddle editor from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you struggling with mixing up both jquery and javascript.? Just use jquery for fetching values from the text box, use `id selector` and `.val()` to accomplish that.

Try,

```
function changeInputBoxText() {
  if($("#inputBox").val() === "Dogs") {
    $("h1").text("I love Dogs");
  } else {
    $("h1").text("Why not dogs?!");
  };
};
```

Or using pure Jquery,

```
$(":button").click(function(){
  $("h1").text(($("#inputBox").val() === "Dogs")?"I love Dogs":"Why not dogs?!");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/c96U7/)

Comment: I added your suggestion and replaced my other code, but when I type anything into the box and click submit, nothing happens still. Is this line of code actually work? $("h1").text("I love Dogs") I want to try to see if it works by isolating it but I'm not sure how since when I just put $("h1").text("I love Dogs") into my script it doesn't change h1.

Comment: @user3764222 have you included jquery library..? Is there any error on console..?

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the answer.  This uses all the new syntax from jquery.  Should it be case sensitive?

Comment: Yes the demo works perfectly! But the first suggestion still doesn't work. (i'm use codacedemy to test since it is simpler).

Comment: @user3764222 Just try to place the code block inside of the header tag and the code block should be the last element inside the header tag...

Comment: I think I figured out my problem! The  codecademy codebit editor i was using doesn't appear to support jquery and others have been having problems with getting jquery to work. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("inputBox").value
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it done by jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('button').click(function()
    {
        if ($('#inputBox").val()==="Dogs")
        {
            $("h1").html("I love Dogs");
        }
        else
        {
            $("h1").html("Why not dogs?!");
        };
    };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (document.getElementById("inputBox").value==="Dogs")
```

check this statement you have missed .value

Answer (score 0):

Using your code it should be like this:

```
function changeInputBoxText()
    {
        if ($("#inputBox").val().trim().indexOf("Dogs")>-1)
        {
            $("h1").html("I love Dogs");
        }
        else
        {
            $("h1").html("Why not dogs?!");
        };
    };
```

Notice that this checks if the user entered Dogs somewhere in the input, so he could enter "I want Dogs" and it'll still count..

Answer (score 0):

test your condition id.value=='test'

```
if (document.getElementById("inputBox").value==="Dogs")
```

[check this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5Cy/)